# Fluent nHibernate QueryOver SQL 'CASE' equivalent

Tags: sql, fluent-nhibernate, case, queryover

Basically what I want to do is to write this piece of SQL:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN t.type = 'a' THEN
        t.name
    ELSE
        t.otherName
    END
    as "Name"
FROM myTable t
```

in QueryOver

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe there is some nicer syntax possible, but this should do

```
var result = session.QueryOver<MyEntity>()
    .Select(Projections.Alias(
        Projections.Conditional(Restrictions.Eq("type", 'a'),
            Projections.Property(t => t.name),
            Projections.Property(t => t.othername)),
        "Name"
    )
    .List();
```